# How to use correlation names in this query

Tags: sql-server

I need to join `PROVIDERS` twice. Will using correlation names work and how can I use it here? Please let me know if I am missing any crucial information in my question.

```
SELECT PROVIDERS.NAME
     , PROVIDERS.CITY
     , PROVIDERS.STATE
     , PROVIDERS.ZIP
     , NPI.[Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] as "ADDRESS"
     , PostalCodes.County                                      
FROM Taxonomy
INNER JOIN       NPI_Taxonomy ON Taxonomy.[Taxonomy Code] = NPI_Taxonomy.[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code] 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS    ON NPI_Taxonomy.NPI = PROVIDERS.FACILITYID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN npi          ON PROVIDERS.FACILITYID = NPI.NPI
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PROVIDERS    ON PostalCodes.Code = PROVIDERS.ZIP 
WHERE     (1=1)
AND (PROVIDERS.STATE = 'AL')
AND ([Taxonomy Specialization] like 'general acute care hospital')
order by PROVIDERS.NAME
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give different `alias name`

```
SELECT P1.NAME, 
       P1.CITY, 
       P1.STATE,
       P1.ZIP, 
       NPI.[Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] as "ADDRESS", 
       PostalCodes.County                                      
FROM Taxonomy
     INNER JOIN NPI_Taxonomy 
     ON Taxonomy.[Taxonomy Code] = NPI_Taxonomy.[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code] 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS P1 ON NPI_Taxonomy.NPI = P1.FACILITYID
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN npi ON P1.FACILITYID = NPI.NPI
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PostalCodes ON PostalCodes.Code = P1.ZIP 
WHERE     (1=1)
AND (P1.STATE = 'AL')
AND ([Taxonomy Specialization] like 'general acute care hospital')
order by P1.NAME
```

`

Comment: I'm still getting the multi-part identifier could not be bound for both `PostalCodes` references.

Comment: @user3749447, you don't have postcodes table in the join atall, i am adding it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias names for the tables:

```
SELECT  PROVIDERS.NAME ,
        PROVIDERS.CITY ,
        PROVIDERS.STATE ,
        PROVIDERS.ZIP ,
        NPI.[Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] AS "ADDRESS" ,
        PostalCodes.County
FROM    Taxonomy
        INNER JOIN NPI_Taxonomy ON Taxonomy.[Taxonomy Code] = NPI_Taxonomy.[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code]
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS p1 ON NPI_Taxonomy.NPI = p1.FACILITYID
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN npi ON p1.FACILITYID = NPI.NPI
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS p2 ON PostalCodes.Code = p2.ZIP
WHERE   ( 1 = 1 )
        AND ( PROVIDERS.STATE = 'AL' )
        AND ( [Taxonomy Specialization] LIKE 'general acute care hospital' )
ORDER BY PROVIDERS.NAME
```

You need to change each PROVIDERS. to p1 or p2 depending on which should be the source of your data.

Comment: I'm still getting the multi-part identifier could not be bound for both PostalCodes references.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the second PROVIDERS join conditions:

```
SELECT PROVIDERS.NAME, PROVIDERS.CITY, PROVIDERS.STATE, PROVIDERS.ZIP, NPI.[Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] as "ADDRESS", PostalCodes.County                                      
FROM Taxonomy
     INNER JOIN NPI_Taxonomy ON Taxonomy.[Taxonomy Code] = NPI_Taxonomy.[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code] 

     --Notice the change

RIGHT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS ON NPI_Taxonomy.NPI = PROVIDERS.FACILITYID and PROVIDERS.ZIP = PostalCodes.Code
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN npi ON PROVIDERS.FACILITYID = NPI.NPI


WHERE     (1=1)
AND (PROVIDERS.STATE = 'AL')
AND ([Taxonomy Specialization] like 'general acute care hospital')
order by PROVIDERS.NAME`
```

Or if you really want a second join you can use aliases.

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS P ON NPI_Taxonomy.NPI = P.FACILITYID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERS P1 on  PostalCodes.Code =  P1.ZIP
```

Just make sure in your select you use the alias(s): `P1.NAME`

But I would recommend the first method with the added join conditions.

Comment: I'm still getting the multi-part identifier could not be bound for both PostalCodes references.

Comment: Sorry please check the updated code. I added aliases without removing the table prefix. 

Can you comment with the problem line(s)?